# Getting the Googlebot crawl errors via R with the new search console

Tags: r, google-search-console

So the problem is I had a code running nicely for an automation that got the number of Googlebot crawl errors. I was using the SearchconsoleR package for this.

Recently I'm assuming that due to the changes in Search Console this doesn't work anymore. Has anyone had (and solved) this problem till now?

So the previous code was working finely for months:

```
Errors <- crawl_errors(website, category = "all", platform = c("web"), latestCountsOnly = T)
```

And now I get the following error code:

```
Request failed [404]. Retrying in 1 seconds...
Request failed [404]. Retrying in 2.4 seconds...
2019-05-15 14:41:02> Request Status Code: 404
Error : lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       Not Found
                     (right here) ------^

Not Found
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       Not Found
                     (right here) ------^
In addition: Warning message:
No JSON content found in request
```

Tried looking into the documentation of the package but didn't find any relevant updates yet. If anyone has any pointers they would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this functionality got removed from the Search Console API.